# Can you colocate jest test files with production files in react-native without them getting bundled?

Tags: react-native, jestjs

In the [Jest documentation for React Native](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-react-native) and in the generated projects I see a dedicated `__tests__` folder outside of the main `src` folder.

However I prefer colocating unit tests with the actual production code, like this:

```
/src/App.tsx
/src/App.test.tsx
```

The **benefit** for me is to

- see if a file has tests already
- easily move components/code with their tests during refactoring

In the latter case I tend to completely forget about things in `__tests__` folder).

#### Question

Is configuration necessary (or possible) for colocating the tests in the above fashion but not getting them bundled in the final `apk`?

Answer (score 0):

Sure! The final architecture decision is yours. Try adding the folders you want to exclude in a `.npmignore`, like described [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package).

Comment: Just to better understand the answer: does `.npmignore` also control what is bundled to the final `apk` file? If so, the solution is fairly straightforward. (Also some people warn against using both `.gitignore` and `.npmignore` and advocate using `package.json` > `files` property: https://medium.com/@jdxcode/for-the-love-of-god-dont-use-npmignore-f93c08909d8d).

Comment: Yep, give a try!

Comment: I have just edited my comment above about hidden risks with `.npmignore`. If `files` work as expected then I can use that, thanks